# Resize 2 containers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wanted to ask how I can automatically resize the two containers here when it is dragged (see picture). It should work so that I can drag in the middle (where the two meet), and the one then becomes larger or smaller.
I can't find anything helpful on the internet :c
At the moment, both containers are in a row.
My code:

```dart
Row(children: [
    Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .5,
            height: double.infinity),
    Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .5,
            height: double.infinity)
])
```

Can someone here maybe help me?

[image]

Comment: You like to resize container based on your tap position?

Comment: Yes, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this widget

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double? leftPart;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        leftPart ??= constraints.maxWidth / 2; // if you need initially half
        return GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
          double tapPos = details.globalPosition.dx;
          const double softPX = 20; //user flexibility
          if (tapPos - 20 < leftPart! && tapPos + 20 > leftPart!) {
            leftPart = details.globalPosition.dx;
            setState(() {});
          }
        },
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: leftPart,
                    height: double.infinity),
              ),
              Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth - (leftPart ?? 0.0),
                  height: double.infinity)
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

If you like to handle overflow on drag, use

```dart
color: Colors.blue,
    width: constraints.maxWidth - (leftPart ?? 0.0) >
            constraints.maxWidth
        ? constraints.maxWidth
        : constraints.maxWidth - (leftPart ?? 0.0) < 0
            ? 0
            : constraints.maxWidth - (leftPart ?? 0.0),
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
Have another small question, I actually just want to be able to drag it in the area where the two containers "meet", at their edges. Is that possible?

Comment: User will be able to drag only when they tap in the middle of it(color join section)?

Comment: I want it to be resizable only when the user has his cursor on that line there (see image) and moves it. Hope you understand what I want 

[Example](https://imgur.com/UhC41fC)

Comment: updated, provided user access+=20px  from collide point.  you can change 20  with the line width

Comment: thank you :) thats exactly what i wanted

Comment: Glad to help, if it for windows you might also like [MouseRegion](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html)